# The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 is invalid while running maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-antrun-plugin

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for :maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version], must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
[ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3

Below is the complete pom.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    tcs.tools
    I2T
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    jar

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>de.viadee.infa2talend.I2TCore</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>de.viadee.infa2talend.I2TCore</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- required to copy the ecore model of Powrmart to the correct location -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-ecore-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/Powrmart/impl</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/java/Powrmart/impl</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- required to copy spring context configuration to test resources -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-spring-context-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>applicationContext-common.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/test/resources/output</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.item</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="${basedir}/template/talend.project" tofile="${basedir}/output/talend.project" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <!-- Additional configuration. -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>

          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>de.viadee.infa2talend.I2TCore</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>

                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0.v20100614-1136</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore-xmi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-jdk1.5</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.3</version>
        <!-- <type>jar</type> -->
        <!-- <optional>false</optional> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mxgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mxgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/jgraphx-1.8.0.3/jgraphx.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<modules>
</modules>
```

Comment: The JDK version being used is 1.8

Comment: It looks you have network firewall/proxy issues cause it looks your download of artifacts has failed...